# Comparing two abap time/date stamps

Tags: date, time, abap

I have two variables:

```
data: 
var_a like sy-timlo,
var_b like sy-timlo.

var_a = sy-timlo.

" do other things here    

var_b = sy-timlo.
```

In case I have a whole bunch of those time-variables, can anyone tell me how I can order them ascending/descending?

Comment: What are you trying to do? How are you expecting to "order variables" if they are simple atomic values? You can "order" (sort) the values contained in a table, but single variables...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates can be compared with simple `LT` and `GT` operations.

If you have a list of Dates in a table, you can sort the table (either ascending or descending), but if your values are stored in a handful of individual variables, you will have to compare them manually and calculate the order based on the comparison results.

I think your best bet is to declare a table of type sy-timlo, add all your variables to that, and then sort the table.